# Calculando el total de los productos con Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estoy intentando agregar productos a una tabla de compras, lo cual funciona bien, el problema viene a la hora de realizar el calculo, entre la cantidad de producto por el precio, sin embargo a la hora de cambiar la cantidad esta no la calcula, he tenido cierto inconveniente a la hora definir dicho calculo ya que el campo de `#producto-quantity` no existe previamente, sino que se crea posteriormente con Javascript, por lo que se me dificulta extraer su id previamente para poder capturar su valor, y asi poder calcularlo, agradecere su ayuda para poder realizarlo esto de forma correcta, comparto a continuacion mi codigo, el error mas especificamente se encuentra en la seccion comentada como: `//Create New HTML Element`

```
<div class="container py-5">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Product List -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <h2>Productos <%= link_to 'Nuevo producto', new_product_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" %></h2>

      <table class="table" id="products">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th class="text-right">Opciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td class="product-id">1</td>
              <td class="product-name">Manzana</td>
              <td class="product-price">0.25</td>
              <td><button class="add-product btn btn-primary">Agregar</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class=product-id">2</td>
              <td class="product-name">Sandia</td>
              <td class="product-price">0.45</td>
              <td><button class="add-product btn btn-primary">Agregar</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="product-id">3</td>
              <td class="product-name">Uva</td>
              <td class="product-price">0.25</td>
              <td><button class="add-product btn btn-primary">Agregar</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <!-- Sale -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Venta</h2>

      <table class="table" id="shopping-list">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio Unit.</th>
                <th>Cant.</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>        
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
      </table>                

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script>

// Get Product Data
function addProduct(e){

  //Get HTML Element
  const getElement = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

  const product = {
    id: getElement.querySelector('.product-id').textContent,
    name: getElement.querySelector('.product-name').textContent,
    price: getElement.querySelector('.product-price').textContent
  }

  // Create New HTML Element 
  const newElement = document.createElement('tr');

  let quantity = 1;
  let itemPrice = product.price * quantity;

  newElement.innerHTML = `
      <td>${ product.id }</td>
      <td>${ product.name }</td>
      <td>${ product.price }</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quantity" class="product-quantity form-control" step="any" value="${ quantity }" /></td>
      <td>${ itemPrice }</td>
      <td><a href="" class="remove-item" id="${ product.id }">X</a></td>
  `;

  // Add Product to Shopping List
  const shoppingList = document.querySelector('#shopping-list tbody');
  shoppingList.appendChild(newElement);

}

// Get All ID Button
let addThis = document.getElementsByClassName('add-product');

for (let i = 0; i < addThis.length; i++){
  addThis[i].addEventListener('click', addProduct);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He añadido un event listener para cada input `type="number"`; Cada vez que cambia el número recalculo el subtotal para el producto y el total de toda la cesta.

Para el input type number he añadido min = 0 porque considero que no es posible comprar -1 uvas. Si quieres hacer devoluciones de productos puedes borrar min = 0;

```js
const shoppingList = document.querySelector('#shopping-list tbody');

// Get Product Data
function addProduct(e){

  //Get HTML Element
  const getElement = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

  const product = {
    id: getElement.querySelector('.product-id').textContent,
    name: getElement.querySelector('.product-name').textContent,
    price: getElement.querySelector('.product-price').textContent
  }

  // Create New HTML Element 
  const newElement = document.createElement('tr');

  let quantity = 1;
  let itemPrice = product.price * quantity;

  newElement.innerHTML = `
      <td>${ product.id }</td>
      <td>${ product.name }</td>
      <td>${ product.price }</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quantity" class="product-quantity form-control" step="any" value="${ quantity }" min="0" /></td>
      <td class="st">${ itemPrice }</td>
      <td><a href="" class="remove-item" id="${ product.id }">X</a></td>
  `;

  // Add Product to Shopping List

  shoppingList.appendChild(newElement);
  calculaElTotal();

}

// Get All ID Button
let addThis = document.getElementsByClassName('add-product');

for (let i = 0; i < addThis.length; i++){
  addThis[i].addEventListener('click', addProduct);
}


shoppingList.addEventListener("input", (e)=>{
  if(e.target.type == "number"){
    let unidades = Number(e.target.value); console.log(unidades);
    
    let tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    
    let precioUnitario = Number(tr.querySelectorAll("td")[2].textContent);console.log(precioUnitario)
    
    let subTotal = unidades * precioUnitario;console.log(subTotal)
    
    let precioTotal = tr.querySelectorAll("td")[4];
    precioTotal.textContent = subTotal;
     
  }
  
calculaElTotal();
})

function calculaElTotal(){
   let total = 0; 
   let tdsArray = Array.from(shoppingList.getElementsByClassName("st"));
   tdsArray.forEach(td =>{
   
   total += Number(td.textContent);console.log(total)
   valor_total.textContent = total;
 })
  
}
```

```css
th,td{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="container py-5">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Product List -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <h2>Productos: 'Nuevo producto', new_product_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" </h2>

      <table class="table" id="products">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th class="text-right">Opciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td class="product-id">1</td>
              <td class="product-name">Manzana</td>
              <td class="product-price">0.25</td>
              <td><button class="add-product btn btn-primary">Agregar</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="product-id">2</td>
              <td class="product-name">Sandia</td>
              <td class="product-price">0.45</td>
              <td><button class="add-product btn btn-primary">Agregar</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="product-id">3</td>
              <td class="product-name">Uva</td>
              <td class="product-price">0.25</td>
              <td><button class="add-product btn btn-primary">Agregar</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <!-- Sale -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Venta</h2>

      <table class="table" id="shopping-list">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio Unit.</th>
                <th>Cant.</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>        
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
      </table>                

    </div>

  </div>

</div>



<div id="valor_total"></div>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto Enxaneta! Basicamente es lo que necesito, solo tengo una duda Enxaneta, la variable valor_total no esta definida en ninguna lado, a pesar que comento esa linea sigue funcionando, por lo que no estoy muy seguro de donde viene

Comment: Es el id del div `<div id="valor_total"></div>`. justo al final del HTML. En JavaScript puedes utilizar los id de elementos como variables.

Comment: Tremendo dato, sinceramente no lo sabia, una ultima duda Enxaneta, en caso de que remueva un item, el total reducira?

Comment: Creo que si, pero tendrías que llamar `calculaElTotal()` de nuevo.

Comment: Por medio de una condicion?

Comment: Para borrar un `tr` tendrás que utilizar algo como `table.removeChild(tr);`y después llamas calculaElTotal(). Si no te sale haz otra pregunta y probaré contestarte.

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo Enxaneta! Lo probare espero funcione =D

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84456/discussion-between-hector-hernandez-and-enxaneta).